# Go regexp to detect backslash character

Tags: regex, go

In go, how do I detect \ back slash character itself?

```
 str := "I have Hello \"World\""
 var validID = regexp.MustCompile(`[.!?]`)
```

this is how I detect . ! ? characters but

```
 var validID = regexp.MustCompile(`[\]`)
```

does not detect the backslash in the string.

How do I denote backslash in go regular expression?

Comment: by your variable name `validID` I'd much more suggest to invert the problem. Ie. to specifically allow certain characters and not look for invalid ons. Things can get hary with escaping, UTF-8 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to escape it, even in a character class; otherwise it will think you're trying to escape the `]`:

```
var validID = regexp.MustCompile(`[\\]`)
```

But for that matter, you can just get rid of the character class entirely:

```
var validID = regexp.MustCompile(`\\`)
```

Also note that the string `"I have Hello \"World\""` does not actually contain any backlashes.  `\"` is an escape sequence a double quote. If you want to create a string with backslashes use:

```
str := "I have Hello \\\"World\\\""
```

Or

```
str := `I have Hello \"World\"`
```

A working demonstration can be found [here](http://play.golang.org/p/31M5bjgbik).